# How to async bundles through angular CLI JSON and angular CLI JSON info

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Two Angular 2 **angular-cli.json** questions here:

1. after running **'ng build --prod'** I can go into my **index.html** file in the newly created **dist** folder and add the **'async'** attribute to the bundled script tags to keep them from being blocking. this helps with website speed but sporadically crashes the site. is there an option in the angular-cli.json that would add this for me during the build in a better way?

i ran my site through google's test my website and the only thing i have left to fix is **Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content**

below is a the more specific result i get from https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
>
> Your page has 4 blocking script resources and 1 blocking CSS
>   resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page. None of the
>   above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting
>   for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously
>   load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those
>   resources directly in the HTML. Remove render-blocking JavaScript:
>
> *****.com/inline.e93ce34d30ab58073e62.bundle.js
>   *****.com/scripts.68b893062974958fa7b3.bundle.js
>   *****.com/vendor.4f05ee5669648be9602e.bundle.js
>   *****.com/main.2d50b916b073e7fba148.bundle.js 
>   Optimize CSS
>   Delivery of the following:
>   *****.com/styles.c9d2a891e3814f5a5ff6.bundle.css

2. Where is a resource for explaining every detail of how the angular-cli.json works? I'm having trouble finding good information on it.

Comment: There is an issue for this you can follow at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3323

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the info, glad to see the Angular team is at least aware of this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by *'ejecting'* your app and using [HTML WEBPACK PLUGIN](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) and its extension plugin [script-ext-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin):

1. run `ng eject -prod`. This command will expose *webpack.config.js* file in your root directory. (to 'uneject' your app again see my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984558/how-to-undo-angular-2-cli-ng-eject/43026220#43026220))
2. Run `npm install` in order to install webpack loaders
3. Install two new plugins:

   ```
   npm i html-webpack-plugin script-ext-html-webpack-plugin -D
   ```
4. In your exposed *webpack.config.js* file edit *plugin* entry and add two plugins in this order:

   ```
   plugins: [
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
     new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
       defaultAttribute: 'async'
     })
   ]
   ```

   [source](https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin#basic-usage)
5. run `npm run build` since `ng build` no longer works on ejected apps.
   After running above command, you should get all scripts set to *async* within *dist* directory.

Comment: It really helped, though I used `defer` instead of `async`!

Comment: `ng enject -prod` does not work on new version of angular

Comment: you are completely right, Angular says that it is "temporarily disabled" starting from v6.0.0 (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10618), and it is documented in changelog (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#possible-breaking-changes)

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo, you can try to use CLI builders instead of `ng eject` - https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/customizing-angular-cli-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-v2-c655768b48cc