# How to undo Angular 2 Cli ng-eject?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have just executed the `ng eject` command. But now I need to revert it, and continue to use `ng` commands. Is it possible?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 69):

At https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/tasks/build.ts#L27 (current angular CLI version: 1.0.1) there is a condition:

```
if (config.project && config.project.ejected) {
  throw new SilentError('An ejected project cannot use the build command anymore.');
}
```

when you run `ng-eject`, *package.json* file is modified with new npm scripts, *webpack.config.js* file is added or replaced and *ejected* flag is added to your *.angular.cli.json*:

```
"project": {
  "name": "YOUR PROJECT NAME",
  "ejected": true
},
```

So, just remove "ejected" flag from your *.angular.cli.json* file:

or change this flag to `false`:

```
"project": {
  "name": "YOUR PROJECT NAME",
  "ejected": false
}
```

Comment: Very helpful answer!I managed to load bootstrap this way!It seems that ng serve is not equal to npm run build & npm start

Comment: If you do the ejection in an isolated commit you might be able to revert the change later by rolling back that commit right?

Comment: actually only package.json you may want to revert, since ng eject may change your scripts section and add dev dependencies (loaders) needed for webpack. Although I noticed that running ng eject with -f flag merges old npm scripts with new added ones, but it should be checked. So, I think, that if your old npm scripts after ng eject are still in package.json and you do not care about loaders, just changing or removing "ejected" flag within *.angular.cli.json* and removing *webpack.config.js * would be enough and you may run all ng commands again. ng eject does not change any custom or core code

Comment: It's a bit inferred above, but if you proceed later to run `ng eject` again (if needed for flags, etc.) after having set `ejected:false` you'll get an error about `project.json` and that it _must not contain a build script_. You'll need to revert the changes within the `scripts` section as well. If you lost the changes, just fire up a new project as a means to an end and copy out the `scripts` section.

Answer (score 3):

With current version of angular cli you need to mark ejected:false or remove the ejected property inside file angular-cli.json file instead of package.json file

Answer (score 1):

This command makes the build configuration part of your project and gets rid of Angular CLI. And also set “ejected”: true in angular-cli.json file , create new file webpack.config.js in project root, and modified run scripts in package.json.

Finally, to undo the ng-eject command it is necessary to modify the package.json file again