# Angular4 build - gzip missing

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run `ng build -prod --aot` only .js files are being produced.

output:

```
chunk    {0} polyfills.a2079361c5ff6d4e321e.bundle.js (polyfills) 285 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.d19edcafc399a0af8c0b.bundle.js (main) 2.33 MB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} scripts.22988bec4cd6ce344e9f.bundle.js (scripts) 973 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} styles.99705fb1bf9015185149.bundle.css (styles) 705 bytes {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} vendor.377addf0a4997a085d42.bundle.js (vendor) 4.71 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} inline.911ff25c95430bbf496e.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
```

My questions are:

1. What happened to the .gz files?
2. How do I serve gzip files from express?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. As stated on [1.0.0-beta.32 (2017-02-17)'s BREAKING CHANGES List](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/ed5f47dc22d5eb4a5d4b4ae2c8f7cb0ec1a999f3/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1),
   since 1.0.0-beta.32

   > @angular/cli: compressed output (.gz) is no longer generated on production builds.

   also, since [1.0.0-beta.28](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/ed5f47dc22d5eb4a5d4b4ae2c8f7cb0ec1a999f3/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-3),

   > --aot defaults to true in --prod

   so, you do not need to add `--aot` flag when running `ng build
   -prod`

   in order to get gz files back you can eject your app by running `ng
   eject` which will expose your *webpack.config.js* file, where you
   can use *[COMPRESSION WEBPACK PLUGIN](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/compression-webpack-plugin)*:

   ```
   const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin"); 
   . . . 
   new CompressionPlugin({})
   ```

   (to 'uneject' your app again see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984558/how-to-undo-angular-2-cli-ng-eject/43026220#43026220))
2. In order to serve gz files from express you can use *[Node JS
   compression middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/compression.html)*:

   ```
   var compression = require('compression')
   var express = require('express')

   var app = express()

   // compress all responses
   app.use(compression())
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Andriy for your comprehensive response. This has helped me a ton!