# Force angular cli gz generation

Tags: css, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm trying to get a dist folder populated with the standard files + the .gz version of them. I did `ng eject` to get the `webpack.config.js` file so I could add the compression plugin https://github.com/webpack-contrib/compression-webpack-plugin. I added the `new CompressPlugin({})` as the last plugin and marked the `ejected: false` in the `.angular-cli.json` file.

When I then run `ng build` I don't get any .gzip/.gz files generated which I would expect have.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? The full webpack file (mostly generated by `ng new` is:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin"); 

const { NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin, SourceMapDevToolPlugin, NamedModulesPlugin } = require('webpack');
const { NamedLazyChunksWebpackPlugin, BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
const { CommonsChunkPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize;
const { AotPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
const realNodeModules = fs.realpathSync(nodeModules);
const genDirNodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', '$$_gendir', 'node_modules');
const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","styles","vendor","main"];
const minimizeCss = false;
const baseHref = "";
const deployUrl = "";
const postcssPlugins = function () {
        // safe settings based on: https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/issues/358#issuecomment-283696193
        const importantCommentRe = /@preserve|@license|[@#]\s*source(?:Mapping)?URL|^!/i;
        const minimizeOptions = {
            autoprefixer: false,
            safe: true,
            mergeLonghand: false,
            discardComments: { remove: (comment) => !importantCommentRe.test(comment) }
        };
        return [
            postcssUrl({
                url: (URL) => {
                    // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
                    if (!URL.startsWith('/') || URL.startsWith('//')) {
                        return URL;
                    }
                    if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//)) {
                        // If deployUrl contains a scheme, ignore baseHref use deployUrl as is.
                        return `${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${URL}`;
                    }
                    else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
                        // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
                        return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') +
                            `/${deployUrl}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                    }
                    else {
                        // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
                        // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
                        return `/${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                    }
                }
            }),
            autoprefixer(),
        ].concat(minimizeCss ? [cssnano(minimizeOptions)] : []);
    };




module.exports = {
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules",
      "./node_modules"
    ],
    "symlinks": true
  },
  "resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules",
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "entry": {
    "main": [
      "./src\\main.ts"
    ],
    "polyfills": [
      "./src\\polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "./src\\styles.css"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js"
  },
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "enforce": "pre",
        "test": /\.js$/,
        "loader": "source-map-loader",
        "exclude": [
          /(\\|\/)node_modules(\\|\/)/
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": /\.html$/,
        "loader": "raw-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(eot|svg|cur)$/,
        "loader": "file-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
        "loader": "url-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]&limit=10000"
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "use": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "precision": 8,
              "includePaths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "use": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "less-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "use": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "stylus-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "paths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "precision": 8,
              "includePaths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "less-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "importLoaders": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "postcss",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "stylus-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "paths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": /\.ts$/,
        "loader": "@ngtools/webpack"
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        "context": "src",
        "to": "",
        "from": {
          "glob": "assets/**/*",
          "dot": true
        }
      },
      {
        "context": "src",
        "to": "",
        "from": {
          "glob": "favicon.ico",
          "dot": true
        }
      }
    ], {
      "ignore": [
        ".gitkeep"
      ],
      "debug": "warning"
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      "exclude": /(\\|\/)node_modules(\\|\/)/,
      "failOnError": false
    }),
    new NamedLazyChunksWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      "template": "./src\\index.html",
      "filename": "./index.html",
      "hash": false,
      "inject": true,
      "compile": true,
      "favicon": false,
      "minify": false,
      "cache": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "chunks": "all",
      "excludeChunks": [],
      "title": "Webpack App",
      "xhtml": true,
      "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
        let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
        let rightindex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
        if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": [
        "inline"
      ],
      "minChunks": null
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": [
        "vendor"
      ],
      "minChunks": (module) => {
                return module.resource
                    && (module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules)
                        || module.resource.startsWith(genDirNodeModules)
                        || module.resource.startsWith(realNodeModules));
            },
      "chunks": [
        "main"
      ]
    }),
    new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      "filename": "[file].map[query]",
      "moduleFilenameTemplate": "[resource-path]",
      "fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate": "[resource-path]?[hash]",
      "sourceRoot": "webpack:///"
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": [
        "main"
      ],
      "minChunks": 2,
      "async": "common"
    }),
    new NamedModulesPlugin({}),
    new AotPlugin({
      "mainPath": "main.ts",
      "replaceExport": false,
      "hostReplacementPaths": {
        "environments\\environment.ts": "environments\\environment.ts"
      },
      "exclude": [],
      "tsConfigPath": "src\\tsconfig.app.json",
      "skipCodeGeneration": true
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({})
  ],
  "node": {
    "fs": "empty",
    "global": true,
    "crypto": "empty",
    "tls": "empty",
    "net": "empty",
    "process": true,
    "module": false,
    "clearImmediate": false,
    "setImmediate": false
  },
  "devServer": {
    "historyApiFallback": true
  }
};
```

I'm using `@angular/cli` `1.4.4`.

Note the main reason why I'm doing that is to improve some SEO recommendations because apparently my vendor.css is 600Kb big and being pointed out in the PageSpeed Ingishts: Your page has 1 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page. It contains 3rd party css only - actually only bootstrap + font-awesome. Unless there is something else to prevent this I thought of compression. I also thought that the web server would auto compress and serve .gz files but I don't know whether that test would apply.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only ejected application's build is processed by exposed on the root `webpack.config.js` file. Application which is not ejected (or set to `ejected: false`) will completely ignore this `webpack.config.js` file.

So in order to use gzipped files you will need to work with ejected app and use new npm scripts automatically added to `package.json`.

Instead of 'ng build', now you should run:

```
npm run build
```

my related answers that may help:

- [Angular4 build - gzip missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005882/angular4-build-gzip-missing/43035273#43035273)
- [How to undo Angular 2 Cli ng-eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984558/how-to-undo-angular-2-cli-ng-eject/43026220#43026220)

Comment: that made sense. I thought the "eject" would only expose the webpack file however I didn't know you had to keep it to let the CLI use it which makes sense on the other hand. Thanks for explaining

Comment: With the latest Angular-cli (1.4.4) I couldn’t manage to get smaller files unless you emit .gz. Thing is that I read that was removed from the cli because the servers now do that for you. In any case this is now sorted, thanks! Would you know by any chance if it is possible to add files to the build depending on the —prod flag in the Angular-cli.json without Ng eject + modifying webpack.config?

Comment: Which files do you want to add to the build, please clarify. You also can add `ng build -prod` command to your `package.json`'s scripts as `build` command and then add `postbuild` command (to `package.json`) which will run automatically after `npm run build`. `postbuild` may execute any bash file which may check production flag and execute desired flow

Comment: Maybe that’s what I have to use then. I want to add the google analytics file when building for PROD only. I also want to get the font files from font awesome to the assets folder (at the moment they get populated in the root of dist)

Comment: Actually I sorted the google analytics thing programmatically using the environment class. Now the only thing I have missing is the fact that font-asweome keeps publishing to the root of the dist folder the font files