# 'ng build' move scripts to subfolder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**ng build** exports files to dist folder as follow

```
index.html  
main.bundle.js  
styles.bundle.js  
...
```

I want scripts to be in subfolder

```
*index.html  
scripts/main.bundle.js  
scripts/styles.bundle.js  
...*
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. run `ng eject -ec` (add '-prod' for production build, or `-aot false` for JIT build). This command will expose *webpack.config.js* file in your root directory. `-ec` flag will extract CSS files (instead of serving them from JS file). (to 'uneject' your app again see my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43026220/1657465))
2. Run `npm install` in order to install webpack loaders
3. In *webpack.config.js* file edit *output* entry and add your desired directory name for JS files:

   `"output": { "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"), "filename": "scripts/[name].[chunkhash:20].bundle.js", "chunkFilename": "scripts/[id].[chunkhash:20].chunk.js" }`
4. because we added `-ec` flag to `ng eject` command, we now have CSS file(s) as well. We can also move it to *dist/styles* by modifying *ExtractTextPlugin* plugin under *plugins* entry in *webpack.config.js* file:

```
`new ExtractTextPlugin({
  "filename": "styles/[name].[contenthash:20].bundle.css",
  "disable": false
}),`
```

5. run `npm run build` since `ng build` no longer works on ejected apps.
   You should get *dist* directory with *scripts* and *styles* directories inside it along with their JS/CSS files, *index.html* should be located directly under *dist* and have correct includes like:

`

`

**Update:**

Since **Angular 7** the eject command has been disabled so this solution will not longer work ([see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54794113/1657465)).

Comment: not only it is not working but it intuitively does not makes sens since these will be used as filenames templates too

Comment: it worked perfectly with current for time of answering version of Angular CLI (I should probably write this version in answer). If you need.help with current version, please specify this version and what exactly you need and I will try to help

Answer (score 0):

you can change the `dist` directory by changing the `outDir` in `angular-cli.json` but you can't set a separate directory for `js` files.

if you want to do that you'll have to write a small node script that runs after build and copies the files you want into `dist/scripts`. You'll also have to change the `<script>` tags inside `index.html` to point to the new location.