# 'ng build' with all scripts in subfolder

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

It is now possible, to get not flat structure of project with `ng build`, so instead of this:

```hs
index.html  
main.bundle.js  
styles.bundle.js  
...
```

I want scripts to be in subfolder

```hs
index.html  
scripts/main.bundle.js  
scripts/styles.bundle.js  
...
```

I found a topic about this: ['ng build' move scripts to subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283915/ng-build-move-scripts-to-subfolder) but hire the solutions is to `eject` project from `cli` into `webpack` but with `Angular 7` this is not longer available and `ng eject` is now disabled:

> The 'eject' command has been disabled and will be removed completely
> in 8.0. The new configuration format provides increased flexibility to
> modify the configuration of your workspace without ejecting.
>
> There are several projects that can be used in conjuction with the new
> configuration format that provide the benefits of ejecting without the
> maintenance overhead.  One such project is ngx-build-plus found here:
> https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus

Angular provide very poor documentation of `angular.json` file hire https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace so it's difficult to use this config file in real project problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot do that by using the [`ng build`](https://angular.io/cli/build) command alone, you can do it by using the following the commands one after the other.

```
ng build --output-path="dist/scripts" --deployUrl="scripts/"
```

and

```
move "dist\scripts\index.html" "dist"
```

The last command works considering that you are using windows (is just a copy/paste, the magic is done by the `--deployUrl` command).

As stated by @Nick in comments, this `options` can also be added on your `angular.json` file:

```js
...
projects: {
  angular: {
     architect: {
        build: {
          options: {
             outputPath: "dist/scripts",
             deployUrl: "scripts/"
          }
        }
     } 
  }
}
```

**Update 09/09/21**:
Angular updated their documentation from `--deployUrl` to `--deploy-url`, they work the same

Comment: I check your solution and it's almost perfect, so thank you for your help. I had 2 more problems - copy files on different systems, so I use gulp task: (mayby you can add this to your answer) `gulp.task('copy-index', function(done) {
  var stream = gulp.src('./dist/app/browser/ng-scripts/index.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/app/browser/'));

  stream.on('end', function() {
    done();
  });
});
` and assets location is now different so I need to move it also.

Comment: These can also be added to the build options in angular.json

Comment: What about assets? I guess I'll have to use environment for that: srcOn1: string = environment.STATIC_FILES_FOLDER + "assets/start/control_start_blue_over.png";

Answer (score 1):

create new file called 'move_assets.js' in the root of the application with the following content.

```
process.argv.forEach(a => {
  if (a.startsWith('--basepath')){
    basepath = a.split('=')[1];
  }
});
var fs = require('fs');
const { interval } = require('rxjs');

var fileCount = null;

if(!basepath){
  console.error('No basepath provided');
}

console.info('Cleaning up file system... Please wait.');
setTimeout(() => {
  console.info('Deleteing old files...');
  fs.readdir(basepath, (err, files) => {
    if(err) {throw err}
    if (files){
      fileCount = files.length;
      files.forEach(item => {
        if(item !== 'scripts'){
          if(fs.existsSync(basepath + item) && fs.lstatSync(basepath + item).isDirectory()){
            fs.rmdir(basepath + item, { recursive: true }, (err) => { if (err) { throw err; } else {fileCount--;}});
          } else {
            fs.unlink(basepath + item, function (err) { if (err) {throw err} else {fileCount--;} });
          }
        }else {
          fileCount--;
        }
      });
    } else {
      fileCount = 0;
    }
  });
}, 1000); //wait for 1 second for file system to breath :)

var timer = setInterval(() => {

  if (fileCount !== null && fileCount < 1) {

    console.info('Moving files.');

    let i = 0;

    const filesToMove = ['assets', 'index.html', 'favicon.ico']
      filesToMove.forEach(f => {
        if(fs.existsSync(basepath + 'scripts/' + f) && (fs.lstatSync(basepath + 'scripts/' + f).isFile() || fs.lstatSync(basepath + 'scripts/' + f).isDirectory())){
          fs.rename(basepath + 'scripts/' + f, basepath + f,function (err) {
            if (err) {throw err}
            else {
              i++;
              console.info(`Successfully moved ${basepath}scripts/${f} --> ${basepath}${f}`);
              if(i == filesToMove.length){
                console.info('Complete!');
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.error(`Cannot move ${basepath}scripts/${f} - item not found`);
        }
    });

    clearInterval(timer);

  }

},500);
```

in package.json file add line in scripts section

```
        "buildWithSubfolder": "ng build --base-href / --deployUrl scripts/ --output-path localfolder/scripts/ && node move_assets.js --basepath=/localfolder/"
```

this will compile an application and dump all the files in the /scripts folder then move index.html, assets, favicon files to the parent folder.