# Exclude files from build in Angular 2

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, tsconfig

How to exclude files from the Angular build using Angular-CLI. I've just added the path to exclude in the `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json` files,  but when I run `ng serve`, Angular is still trying to compile the files.

Any ideas?

Comment: it would be really great if you could just put ng-exclude or something at the top of a file. editing an entirely separate file seems a bit much.  I dog vs a lot, but 'right click-exclude file' really comes in handy in many scenarios.... credit where credit is due...

Comment: Sometimes it's just easier to go to the documentation! https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig

Answer (score 21):

Using `exclude` property of [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) (at root level), i.e.:

```json
{
   "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "**/*.spec.ts"
   ]
}
```

Comment: That is what I tried but it still trying to compile the typescript files

Comment: What typescript files?

Comment: I have some typescript files in a folder, but I don't want to compile them.

Comment: post your typscript files and all related artifacts.

Comment: I just want that the compiler ignore a folder, is it important the files content?

Comment: I think another issue is that if any of the files that are included reference files that are excluded it still gets compiled.

Comment: What's the difference between doing this in `tsconfig.json` (root) vs `tsconfig.app.json`?

Comment: Regarding the difference between different tsconfig files see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898013/difference-between-tsconfig-json-and-tsconfig-app-json-files-in-angular

Comment: I want to exclude the folder ```src/assets/mock```. I tried with ```{ "exclude": [ "src/assets/mock"  ] }```, ```{ "exclude": [ "/src/assets/mock"  ] }```, ```{ "exclude": [ "./src/assets/mock"  ] }```, ```{ "exclude": [ "**/src/assets/mock"  ] }```, ```{ "exclude": [ "**/mock"  ] }```, ```{ "exclude": [ "**/mock/**"  ] }``` and many other combinations that I had the patience to try. I tried these values in tsconfig.json, in tsconfig.app.json, as well as angular.json wiht "ignore" instead of "exclude". As with many things Angular, it doesn't "just work".

Answer (score 15):

In your angular.json file,edit the build section as follows :

```json
...
  "assets": [
    "src/assets",
    "src/favicon.ico"
  ],
  "styles": [
    "src/styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": []
},
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "assets": [
      {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets/",
        "ignore": [
          "**/test.json",
          "**/test"
        ],
        "output": "/assets/"
      },
      {
        "glob": "favicon.ico",
        "input": "src/",
        "output": "/"
      }
    ],
...
```

This will still do the default imports required,but remove the specified files/directories(test.json & /test) when running ng build --prod,however they will still be available via ng serve,which is great for local development.

Remember to also exclude in your `.gitignore` file if you have sensitive information in those files.

I could not make it work when editing `tsconfig.json`,but the above worked like a charm!

Solution based on an example found [here](https://www.w3resource.com/angular/angular-workspace-configuration.php)

Answer (score 3):

I noticed if you put a `.` in front of the path it will work:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "exclude": [
    ...
    "./yourPathToExclude/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can this be per build type?

Answer (score 3):

## Angular 7

I added the regex for the files to exclude from the build to `src/tsconfig.app.json`.

### Example:

Suppose I added the file `./src/app/components/my-component/my-component.stub.ts` to help in unit tests.

`npm run build` and `ng serve --prod=true` commands by default exclude only files ending with `...spec.ts` and include all other files.

In order to exclude the above file, add a regular expression to the `src/tsconfig.app.json` as follows:

```
"exclude": [
    "**/*.stub.ts"
]
```

Angular will exclude any file in the project that ends with `.stub.ts` from the build commands.

Full `src/tsconfig.app.json` example:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.stub.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng eject` to get the webpack.config.js. You can modify this to your needs. However, you will not be able to use `ng serve` or `ng build` after that.

For using these commands again, you have to modify `.angular-cli.json`. Remove the property 'projects.ejected' or set it to false. [How to undo Angular 2 Cli ng-eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984558/how-to-undo-angular-2-cli-ng-eject)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that might work in some situations.

In angular.json (located in an Angular project's root directory), you will see this file replacement block in the build configurations for the production environment by default.

```
"fileReplacements": [
  {
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
],
```

Just add your own file replacements there, and anything in the replaced file will not be compiled into the app.

```
"fileReplacements": [
  {
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
  },
  {
    "replace": "src/yourconfig.ts",
    "with": "src/yourconfig.prod.ts"
  }
],
```

Imports no longer used by the replaced file will also be ignored by the app, so, using the above example, if the ignored config file references a bunch of other environment specific files, they will also be ignored.

You can also do this for any number of environments: https://angular.io/guide/build

Answer (score 0):

I don't found a way to remove a folder ONLY in production mode.
With `tsconfig` either with `angular.json` build config

The only way (not "clean") i found to do that is to remove the folder after the build.

For instance my `package.json`:

```
    ...
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production && npm run removeMocks",
    "removeMocks": "rimraf dist/myProject/mocks"
    ...
```

This Angular CLI thread is closed but not answered :
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6050#issuecomment-422288566