# Angular cli prevent recompile when folder update

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm working on an Angular 4 project using Angular CLI but it's recompiling everything time there is any change on any folder on the project I'm working on.

For example, I'm working on a file uploader and I can't properly test it, because when a file is uploaded, the app is recompiled and reloads, so the function never finishes.

Is there a way to prevent this to happen? It would be ideal to just disable the "watch" on a single folder, which is the `assets` folder.

I tried to remove it from the `angular-cli.json` file but it made no difference, it's still recompiling everything.

I also tried to add an exclude option to the files `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json` but it's also still recompiling everything.

I added the exclude like this:

```
// tsconfig.app.json
"exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "/app/assets/**/*"
]

// tsconfig.json
"exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "./src/app/assets/**/*"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to: [Angular 2 - Exclude files from build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952811/angular-2-exclude-files-from-build/45143621#45143621)

You can use `ng eject` to get the webpack.config.js. You can modify this to your needs. However, you will not be able to use `ng serve` or `ng build` after that.

For using these commands again, you have to modify `.angular-cli.json`. Remove the property 'projects.ejected' or set it to false. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984558/how-to-undo-angular-2-cli-ng-eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984558/how-to-undo-angular-2-cli-ng-eject.)