# is it possible to exclude files from angular library?

Tags: angular, angular-library

While we build a angular library, is it possible to exclude certain folders that are present within the library, for eg : a sub library.

I am trying to add the exclude option in the library build json as follows:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "src/app/modules/upload/ng-package.json",
           "exclude":[
              "src/app/modules/*"
            ]
          }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude files from build in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952811/exclude-files-from-build-in-angular-2)

Comment: i tried it, but when i include the same in library configuration, it is throwing error as"schema validation failed with the following errors :Data "path: should not have additional properties [ exclude ]