# angular cli eject works, how do i un-eject

Tags: angular-cli

ng eject "discloses the webpack.config.js file" that I wanted to see.

But -ng build- gives me an error: "An ejected project cannot use the build command anymore". I did not see a webpack cli re-integration path.  ng cli does not have a way to re-integrate webpack from its help

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5229  Does not answer the question.

What are the steps to restore ng build?

Comment: Yes,  I added the answer below to specify that after more searching yesterday.  Should I delete the question,  I am relatively new to this?

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer here: [How to undo Angular 2 Cli ng-eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984558/how-to-undo-angular-2-cli-ng-eject)

go to angular-cli.json and remove "ejected": true

Answer (score 0):

un eject it because for it to make the make for the eject purpose you need to have the thing done